# Ghostscript mswinpr2 prints monochrome unless BitsPerPixel=24 which creates very large spool file

Tags: ghostscript

6 July 2018

Hi Ken, thank you for all your information! I'm sorry it took a while to get back to you but based on your advice we went away and did some work.  We are now down to about 10.4MB at 100dpi.
Our problem at this low resolution is fonts and barcode integrity.

So far the only way we have managed great spool file size is by using Adobe's AcroRd32.exe via command line.  This gives amazing sizes of around 2.5MB.  Resolution seems fine and crucially barcodes and fonts are fine too.  However using this method with high volume printing would not be ideal.

Do you have any idea why printing in this way creates such small spool file size?   We are having some colour issues but resolution seems very good.

What makes AcroRd32.exe different to everything else we’ve tried so far?  Your advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you. 
Lizl

---

I need to print an image heavy pdf catalogue via ghostscript.  If I do not reduce the resolution, the spool file becomes very big.
Ultimately we need to print the pdf files over a VPN connection which means that the file size needs to stay around 5MB or lower.  We are happy with a resolution of around 300 dpi.

This command creates a 1.74 MB file:

> C:\Users\admin>"c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.23\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dNOPAUSE
>   -dQUIET -dBATCH -c "mark /OutputFile (%printer%Pro C5100Sseries E-22B PS 1.1) /UserSettings <> (mswinpr2) finddevice
>   putdeviceprops setdevice" -f "myCatalogue.pdf"

This command creates a 84.7MB file:

> c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.23\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET
>   -dBATCH -c "mark /BitsPerPixel 24 /OutputFile (%printer%Pro C5100Sseries E-22B PS 1.1) /UserSettings <>
>   (mswinpr2) finddevice putdeviceprops setdevice" -f "myCatalogue.pdf"

The pdf prints in monochrome if I do not specify /BitsPerPixel 24.  However that pushes file size up to 84.7MB.

Found this explanation online:
*Some Windows device drivers erroneously return a low value
that causes the BitsPerPixel which can force us to map to monochrome, dithered even on a full color device, making -dBitsPerPixel=24 mandatory.*

Is there anybody else that has experienced this problem or any suggestions on alternative ways to batch print pdf files over VPN with files sizes no more than 5MB?

Comment: Hi Ken, thank you for all your information! I'm sorry it took a while to get back to you but based on your advice we went away and did some work.

Answer (score 0):

The way mswinpr2 works is to render the input file to a bitmap, then blit the bitmap to the Windows device context, then tell the device context to print it. That invokes the print pipeline which uses the Windows printer driver to create a file suitable for the printer to read.

Depending on the printer, this could be PCL, PostScript, XPS, GDI or some other language proprietary to the printer manufacturer (eg ZPL for Zebra printers).

The advantage of working this way is that it leverages the vast support of Windows for specific printer types. Otherwise Ghostscript would have to have a driver for every single different printer, which long ago became an impossible task.

The disadvantage of course is that what gets printed is a huge bitmap. So its big.

If you consider a 300 dpi A4 page, 8 bits per component RGB, then the image will be:

width in inches * resolution (dpi) * bits per sample (24)

8.27 * 300 * 3 = 7443 bytes per scan line

Then there are:

height in inches * resolution (dpi) scan lines on the page
11.69 * 300 = 3507

So we multiply the scan line size * the number of scan lines to get the image size:

7443 * 3507 = 26,102,601 bytes or a little under 25 MB

So your goal of an image of 5 MB would require you to compress the file and get a compression ratio at least 5:1. So one solution would be to try zipping the file and unzipping at the other end.

Now, one of the things about this device is that its properties are controlled by the **printer**. The Ghostscript device queries the printer and adjusts itself to the resolution of the printer. I suspect your printer is actually set up to render at 600 dpi, which is why your spool file is 4 times larger than a 300 dpi resolution would suggest.

The device also doesn't support reducing the colour quality, other than to monochrome (which is what I suspect your 1.74MB file is). So your choice is monochrome, 1 bit per component CMYK or 24-bit RGB.

You can find the documentation on the Ghostscript devices on the Ghostscript web site, and the specifics for this device [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/Devices.htm#Win)

About the only thing you can do (and I haven't tried this) is set the MaxResolution parameter. But as I've shown above, that will only get you to 25Mb. If you want lower than that you'd have to reduce the resolution still further. To get a further drop by a factor of 5 would mean more than halving the resolution.

Looks like you'd be looking at about 135 dpi.